# magento insert description block into 1column template ( product view )

Tags: xml, magento, layout, block

my product view is currently `setTemplate` as follow:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>........
```

and I also see my description block is referred inside its child  as follow

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
```

Therefore I went into my 1column.phtml and insert the the description block as follow :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('description') ?>
```

but it does not show at the product page

Any advise greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the levels. With reference to the *root* you set to the 1-column template, but description is referenced to the *content*, not the 1-column file.

Content is defined in *page.xml* and its defined as *core/text_list*, which means:

> When defined in a layout, any block of type core/text_list will
>   automatically render all its children.

So any defined children will be rendered. If you really want to call the description from 1-column template use something like:

```
echo $this->getChildChildHtml('content','description');
```